# Multidimensional session php array echoing

Tags: php, arrays, session, multidimensional-array, echo

I have a PHP session array where it can be counted as multidimensional array, basically I am trying to store data inside my session array and i am successfully obtaining that part of the task. The main issue is, I am not able to echo them specifically and I have to use var_dump. When I try to print them with echo i got an notice which says array to string conversion. Please any help I would be appreciated how to print them with their own specific keys or values. The code as follows:

```
if (!is_array($_SESSION['products']['names'])){

  $_SESSION['products']['names'] = array();
  $_SESSION['products']['names']['prices']= array();

  }else {

    $pros = $_SESSION['products']['names'];

    if (in_array($product->getName(), $pros, true)){

    echo 'The product is available in your basket';

  } else {

    array_push($_SESSION['products']['names'],$product->getName());
    array_push($_SESSION['products']['names']['prices'], $product->getPrice(Currency::getCurrentCurrency()));


    foreach ($_SESSION['products']  as  $val){

      echo $val['names'];
      echo $val['prices'];

    }
  }

}
```

The output that I receive as follows:

Notice: Undefined index: names in

Array to string conversion in

Comment: `print_r` prints variable perfect. On what line of this code do you encounter a problem?

Comment: The print_r line because it prints it with quotes, where i do not want it to be really. Because echo helps to print it more clearly and the way i want to print

Comment: `echo` prints strings only. Array is not a string. You have to use `foreach` and print every item of your array.

Comment: that is what i am trying to do actually, can you help me on that how can i print it them with foreach

Answer (score 1):

Use [join()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) function in your foreach, like this:

```
echo join('<br>', $val);
```

Or instead of

```
echo $val['prices'];
```

write

```
echo $val['names']['prices'];
```

Comment: do you have more efficient solution for it ?

Comment: I think you should completly restructure this code. Stg like $_SESSION['products'] could contain all the details in an associative array: id,name,price etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem...

```
// Here your assigning `['names']` as a string..
array_push($_SESSION['products']['names'],$product->getName());

// Then here you're overwriting the string with an array...
array_push($_SESSION['products']['names']['prices'], $product->getPrice(Currency::getCurrentCurrency()));
```

Change the first one to this..

```
array_push($_SESSION['products']['names']['name'],$product->getName());
```

Assuming `$product->getPrice()` returns a string or a number...

```
foreach ($_SESSION['products']  as  $val){
    foreach($val['names'] as $name){
        echo $name['name'];
        echo $name['prices'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Partly it does the work but still array to string conversion error

Comment: No solution full of notice :) Undefined names
I don no know what to do really

Comment: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

Undefined index: names in

 Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Answer (score -1):

There is no issue with the code you have here.  I don't see you trying to echo or vardump them directly so please show the code you are echoing them out specifically or the output from above and which line is giving you an issue.

Comment: here's an array.. `array_push($_SESSION['products']['names'],$product->getName());` ..here's an array to string conversion `echo $val['names'];` .. obviously there IS something wrong with his code

Comment: @Pamblam echo $val['names'] wasn't the original code shown. The code has changed

Comment: yes he is right i have changed to code sorry for confusion

Comment: oh, well i'll remove the downvote if the answer is edited.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to echo each one out with it's price.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['products']['names']);$i++) {
echo $_SESSION['products']['names'][$i] . " " . $_SESSION['products']['names']['price'][$i];
}
```

Comment: that's because "names" is an associative array, there is no `['names'][$i]`

Comment: What error did you get?  @Pamblam array_push does not create an associative array